# Multiple Status on a Membership?

Tags: civimember, status

I know that there can be overlapping status' for a membership, and that the order can be set to determine which status takes precedence.

I'm curious if it's possible to have both status' display.  For example our non-profit categorizes members who are paid up on dues as in 'good standing' but we have a period of 2 months they could miss dues and still be in good standing before falling into 'bad standing.'  We would like to have a status for 'good standing', 'good standing 1 month behind on dues', and 'good standing 2 months behind on dues' so that we could better follow up with members who are behind on dues.

I know we could probably just do a status for each month behind, but we had previously set up 'good', 'bad', and 'inactive' standings,  and have various smart-groups and permissions set up around that.  So it would be easier if we could add other status' on top of the memberships' main status.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The membership status ID field on a membership record is a single-value field - so this isn't doable without adding the new membership statuses.  I'd recommend either a) adding the new statuses and updating your smart groups, or b) creating reports based on membership end dates to use those to follow up with members.